# mysql select union doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql

Mysql version 5.1.
Code example:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM abonents WHERE `session_id`='$current_sess_id' UNION SELECT * FROM abonents_problem WHERE `session_id`='$current_sess_id' UNION SELECT * FROM abonents_stop WHERE `session_id`='$current_sess_id'");
```

Runs if remove "UNION", example:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM abonents WHERE `session_id`='$current_sess_id'" );
```

"WTF Code" forever =):

```
$rez_11_one = mysql_query(
        "SELECT * FROM abonents WHERE `session_id`='$current_sess_id'"
    );
    $rez_11_two = mysql_query(
        "SELECT * FROM abonents_problem WHERE `session_id`='$current_sess_id'"
    );
    $rez_11_three = mysql_query(
        "SELECT * FROM abonents_stop WHERE `session_id`='$current_sess_id'"
    );
    if ($rez_11_one) {
        $rez_11 = $rez_11_one;
    } elseif ($rez_11_two) {
        $rez_11 = $rez_11_two;
    } else {
        $rez_11 = $rez_11_three;
    }
```

Thank's for help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

reference to the mysql documentation `UNION` only works if all querys return the same number of `columns`.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/union.html

therefore as you use a selector asterisks `*` i think the tables have a different amount of columns. use `select` eg

`SELECT 1,2 FROM foo UNION SELECT 1,2 FROM bar`

to get per query the same amount of columns.

Answer (score 0):

Try query without "*"
Like this

```
mysql_query("SELECT <table_column_name> FROM abonents WHERE `session_id`='$current_sess_id' UNION SELECT <table_column_name> FROM abonents_problem WHERE `session_id`='$current_sess_id' UNION SELECT <table_column_name> FROM abonents_stop WHERE `session_id`='$current_sess_id'");
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add escape characters to the string to make it:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM abonents WHERE \`session_id\`=\'$current_sess_id\' UNION SELECT * FROM abonents_problem WHERE \`session_id\`=\'$current_sess_id\' UNION SELECT * FROM abonents_stop WHERE \`session_id\`=\'$current_sess_id\'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure if the query returns the same number of columns..According to the documentation of `UNION`.It only works if the query returns same number of columns